# Plone 4: collective.formcriteria uninstall now can't import site

Tags: plone, python-import, buildout

I had collective.formcriteria installed on a site, then it was uninstalled & removed from Buildout.

When I export my site it works fine, but trying to import the site gives me this error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):

    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 127, in publish
    Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
    Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 47, in call_object
    Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 628, in manage_importObject
    Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 646, in _importObjectFromFile
    Module ZODB.ExportImport, line 92, in importFile
    Module transaction._transaction, line 253, in savepoint
    Module transaction._transaction, line 250, in savepoint
    Module transaction._transaction, line 647, in __init__
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 1128, in savepoint
    Module ZODB.Connection, line 570, in _commit
    Module ZODB.ExportImport, line 175, in _importDuringCommit

ImportError: No module named formcriteria.criteria.relativepath
```

Will installing this addon again and attempting to import/export my site work or is there another fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you include the full traceback from the logs as well?

Comment: Traceback: [link](http://pasteit.com/18049)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During import the ZODB has to remap the persistent ids in the dumped pickles, and to do so it has to 'load' all the entries in your export file.

During that remapping process it thus will try and import every referenced class. Your export still holds references to `collective.formcriteria` classes, and that's why you get the error during import.

There are two things you can do:

1. Install `collective.formcriteria` into your buildout just for this import to work. There is no need to run install code or anything, the Zope process just needs to be able to import the class during the import process. You can remove it again afterwards.
2. Fill in the missing imports with empty stubs. This is a bit more involved, as you'll need to create a dummy module that you'll insert into `sys.modules` to be loaded for this process.

   The dummy module could look like this; I've named it 'placeholder.py':

   ```
   from persistent import Persistent

   class PlaceHolderClass(Peristent):
       def __repr__(self):
           return "<Persistent placeholder class for now-removed instances>"
   ```

   And you stub out missing imports with:

   ```
   import sys
   import placeholder

   sys.modules['collective.formcriteria.criteria.relativepath'] = placeholder

   placeholder.FormRelativePathCriterion = placeholder.PlaceHolderClass
   ```

   It is quite likely you'll need to stub out more such classes, based on the [`collective.formcriteria` package layout](https://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/collective.formcriteria/trunk/src/collective/formcriteria/).

   Using this technique does not remove the broken references; it'll only let you import your `.zexp` file into a new instance.

Comment: Thank you but I quickly imported the content from the old site into a new fresh Plone site (in my work I'm not really allowed to access the server via the CLI). Thank you for your answer though

Comment: +1, you're not only an expert, you also know, how to transport it to the people in a comprehensive way, appreciate that a lot.